# Update sql java doesn't work

Tags: java, sqlite, sql-update

I am working on Java Application and trying so hard to update record in SQLite database but it doesn't work .. btw it doesn't give me any exceptions or errors

```
 String sql="update Food_Fresh set available=? where Type_ID =?";
             st=con.prepareStatement(sql);
             st.setInt(1, 1);
             st.setInt(2, num);
             st.executeUpdate();

             st.close();
```

What's the problem ?!

UPDATE
yes , the initialization of sql

```
try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Shatha2012\\Desktop\\Core\\IT\\Graduation Project\\Code\\New folder\\Food\\src\\Food\\Food.sqlite");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DONE");
        return con;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the committing is set as auto commit

Comment: The problem could be in a no of places. Please try printing out the final SQL (right before the st.executeUpdate()) and then running that query directly into SQLite.

Comment: Are you sure you're committing your transaction?

Comment: Wild guess: switch parameters 1 and 2. You submit the amount to 1 always for different Ids (named num?!)

Comment: Are you sure that the "sql" was correctly initialized ? Can you show us how you initialize it ?

Comment: I've updated the Q. ,,Check it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are no records in your database with Type_ID = num?
Check the value returned from executeUpdate()

```
int i = st.executeUpdate();
```

it will show you the number of records updated

Comment: it is about 20 .. but when I checked the db ... nothing changed !